# return first date in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I try to create a new feature that shows the minimum (lowest) data of a given group.

My data looks as follows:

| animal_id | cycle_nr | feed_date | start_date_cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-06 | 2020-09-20 |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-10 | 2020-09-20 |
| 1 | B | 2021-02-14 | 2020-09-20 |
| 2 | A | 2021-02-20 | 2020-09-30 |
| 2 | A | 2021-02-21 | 2020-09-30 |

For every `animal_id` and `cycle_nr`, I want to return the first `feed_date`.

My desired df would look like this

| animal_id | cycle_nr | feed_date | start_date_cycle | first_feed_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-06 | 2020-09-20 | 2021-02-06 |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-10 | 2020-09-20 | 2021-02-06 |
| 1 | B | 2021-02-14 | 2020-09-20 | 2021-02-14 |
| 2 | A | 2021-02-20 | 2020-09-30 | 2021-02-20 |
| 2 | A | 2021-02-21 | 2020-09-30 | 2021-02-20 |

I have tried multiple things, but none of these options return the correct value:

```
df['first_feed_date'] = df.groupby(['animal_id', 'cycle_nr']).agg({'feed_date' : np.min})
df['first_feed_date'] = df.loc[df.groupby(['animal_id', 'cycle_nr'])['feed_date'].idxmin()]
df['first_feed_date']= df.groupby(["animal_id", "cycle_nr"])["feed_date"].transform(min)
df['first_feed_date'] = df.groupby(["animal_id", "cycle_nr"])["feed_date"](['first'])
```

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

Firstly convert 'feed_date' and 'start_date_cycle' columns to datetime:

```
df['feed_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['feed_date'])
df['start_date_cycle']=pd.to_datetime(df['start_date_cycle'])
```

Finally use `groupby()` and `transform()`:

```
df['first_feed_date']=df.groupby(["animal_id", "cycle_nr"])['feed_date'].transform('first')
```

output of `df`:

```
  animal_id     cycle_nr        feed_date   start_date_cycle    first_feed_date
0   1           A               2021-02-06  2020-09-20          2021-02-06
1   1           A               2021-02-10  2020-09-20          2021-02-06
2   1           B               2021-02-14  2020-09-20          2021-02-14
3   2           A               2021-02-20  2020-09-30          2021-02-20
4   2           A               2021-02-21  2020-09-30          2021-02-20
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually using `drop_duplicates` then `merge`

```
out = df.merge(df.sort_values('feed_date').drop_duplicates(['animal_id','cycle_nr']).drop('start_date_cycle',1).rename(columns={'feed_date':'1st_feed_date'}))
Out[33]: 
   animal_id cycle_nr  feed_date start_date_cycle 1st_feed_date
0          1        A 2021-02-06       2020-09-20    2021-02-06
1          1        A 2021-02-10       2020-09-20    2021-02-06
2          1        B 2021-02-14       2020-09-20    2021-02-14
3          2        A 2021-02-20       2020-09-30    2021-02-20
4          2        A 2021-02-21       2020-09-30    2021-02-20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
df1.groupby(['State'])['Sales'].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['animal_id', 'cycle_nr']).first()
```

Try this [Aggregate return First](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/10/pandas-groupby-13-functions-to-aggregate/#:%7E:text=Pandas%20groupby%3A%20first(),row%20value%20within%20each%20group.&text=In%20our%20example%2C%20we%20get,population%20value%20in%20each%20continent.)